# Java - Creating BulkConnection object with Oauth token

Tags: api, java, oauth, bulk

I have successfully been able to create a bulk API connection with the following code that calls the SOAP auth endpoint:

```
    ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
    partnerConfig.setUsername(user);
    partnerConfig.setPassword(pass);

    partnerConfig.setProxy(proxy, port);
    partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0");

    new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);

    ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
    config.setSessionId(partnerConfig.getSessionId());

    String soapEndpoint = partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint();
    String apiVersion = "41.0";
    String restEndpoint = soapEndpoint.substring(0, soapEndpoint.indexOf("Soap/")) + "async/" + apiVersion;

    config.setRestEndpoint(restEndpoint);
    config.setCompression(true);
    config.setTraceMessage(false);

    config.setProxy(host, port);

    BulkConnection connection = new BulkConnection(config);
```

After getting the BulkConnection object, I can make the necessary calls I need to manipulate data. But now I want to be able to create this object with using an access token that I receive from an Oauth call instead of authenticating with SOAP.

I'm able to retrieve the token with no issue but I'm confused as to how I can use the token afterwards to authenticate. I'm pretty sure I have to provide the token to the ConnectorConfig somehow but I can't come up with the right configuration (rest endpoint, auth endpoint, session id, etc) that's specific to oauth.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I needed to set the ConnectorConfig's sessionId to be the token which allowed me to use the BulkConnection object in the same manner as before.

```
    ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
    config.setSessionId(accessToken);
    config.setRestEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
    config.setCompression(true);
    config.setTraceMessage(false);

    config.setProxy(host, port);

    BulkConnection connection = new BulkConnection(config);
```